# How to update Bing Maps or Google Maps dynamically, depending on the address given to it

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

On a project I'm building, I want the user to be able to select an address which is stored in the database, and then click on that address to view more information. When the user clicks on the link, it will take them to another page which will display more information, as well as a Map of the address.

What I want to do is get the map to locate the address dynamically, instead of using a pre-defined embed link. But I'm not entirely sure if what I want to do can be done, and if it can be done I don't know how to do it.

So essentially, I want to know how I can take the address from the database, and pass it to the embedded map on my project?

It doesn't really make a difference to me if Bing or Google is used.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you want can easily be done.  Both [Bing Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427601.aspx) and [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) offer geocoding services, where you give the service an address, and the services returns as part of its results longitude and latitude coordinate of the address on the map.  I could paste a bunch of code here but you can find all the code sample you need for both maps in my links above.

When the user clicks on your address link, you bring them to your detailed information page.  On that page, you will have javascript to set up your map.  In addition to the javascript setting up your map, you will need more javascript, detailed in the links above, to call the geolocation services.  In essences, you pass to the services the address you want to look up, and if the address is valid the service will return to you the longitude and latitude coordinates of that address.  Using this information, you can then zoom to that location on the map, and optionally put a pushpin there to indicate the address.

See here for an [example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html) in google maps.

[Interactive SDK of Bing Maps](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#RESTServices1)  Click on REST Services -> Find a location by query.

I am assuming you are interested in the ajax version of the map controls, but the other versions should be quite similar and should work more or less the same.

Comment: Thank you for all of this, it's amazed me how powerful these map services are! I've plumbed for Bing as I like the look of the map better than that of Google. Thanks again!

Comment: @mickburkejnr No problem.  One thing to keep in mind is if you want to go commercial with your application, Bing Maps in general is a lot cheaper to use than Google Maps.  However Google Maps currently has better Ortho Imagery than Bing Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
<div id="location"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var gpLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var gpOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: gpLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("location"), gpOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: gpLatlng, 
            map: map, 
            title:"Title"
        });
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize&region=GB";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```